# Relationship between integrability and bounded variation property

Tags: real-analysis, integration

If a function $f$ is Riemann-integrable on a compact interval $[a,b]$, must it be of bounded variation ?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

No, $[0,1] \ni t \mapsto \begin{cases} 0, & t=0, \\ t \sin(1/t), & t >0, \end{cases}$ is continuous, so it is Riemann-integrable, but it is not of bounded variation.

Comment: For the sake of completeness, [$t\sin(1/t)$ is Riemann Integrable](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/529463). Further, it has [unbounded variation](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/605241)