# Is $f(x)=x\sin(\frac{1}{x})$ with $f(0)=0$ of bounded variation on $[0,1]$?

Tags: real-analysis, bounded-variation

I can't figure out whether $f(x)=x\sin(1/x)$ with  $f(0)=0$ is of bounded variation on $[0,1]$ or not.

But I think it is not. Can someone suggest a partition to prove it is not of bounded variation is so? Thanks

Comment: Do you define it as $0$ at $x=0$? Look for values of (1/x) for which the sin takes values $1$ and $-1$ respectively.

Comment: @DBFdalwayse yes I missed that I edited my posted

Comment: :No problem. It helps to do a plot , e.g., in Wolfram:http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=plot+xsin%281%2Fx%29%3D . Maybe you could try for $x^2sin(1/x)$ now. Of course, looking at a plot is not a substitute for the actual calculations.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Sure. Try $x_n=\frac1{n\pi+\pi/2}$ for every $n\geqslant0$.

Comment: The point being, since it is the $\sin(1/x)$ factor that is the wiggly one, to pick the extreme values of that part, i.e., where it is $\pm1$.

Comment: But it is interesting to see how/why a higher power of $x$--$x^2$ itself is enough, slows the wiggling enough to make the function BVD.

Answer (score 24):

Consider the partition defined by $\{x_n\}=\{\frac{1}{n\pi+\pi/2}\}$,

$$ \sin (1/x_n)=\left\{\begin{array} \{1 \qquad n \text{ is even}\\-1 \qquad n \text{ is odd}\>\end{array}\right.\qquad\text{for }n\geq 0$$ Hence $$ f(x_n)=x_n\sin(1/x_n)=\left\{\begin{array} \{x_n \qquad n \text{ is even}\\-x_n \qquad n \text{ is odd}\>\end{array}\right.\qquad\text{for }n\geq 0$$
Therefore $$\sum_{n=1}^m|f(x_n)-f(x_{n-1})|=\sum_{n=1}^m|(-1)^n(x_n+x_{n-1})|= \sum_{n=1}^m(x_n+x_{n-1})\\=x_m+x_0+2\sum_{n=1}^{m-1}x_n\\\geq \sum_{n=1}^{m-1} x_n=\sum_{n=1}^{m-1} \frac{1}{n\pi+\pi/2}.$$ We see that $$\sum_{n=1}^{m-1} \frac{1}{n\pi+\pi/2}\to \infty \qquad \text{ as }\qquad m\to \infty.$$ Since $V_0^1(f)$ is not bounded in this partition, $V_0^1(f)$ is not bounded variation function.

In general, the function $$ f(x)=x^a\sin(1/x^b), \qquad x\in[0,1] $$ is not bounded variation for $0<a\leq b$.

Comment: $$\sum_{n=1}^{m-1} \frac{1}{n\pi+\pi/2}\to \infty \qquad \text{ as }\qquad m\to \infty.$$ Why is this true?

Comment: Use the Limit Comparison Test with the series $\sum_{n = 1}^{m - 1} \frac{1}{n}$

Comment: for the general rule of above can we say that the partition could be also in this form?
$$x_n = \{\frac{1}{(n\pi + \frac{\pi}{2})^{\frac{1}{b}}} \}$$

Comment: The thing I don't get is that, as far as I'm concerned, the partition of [0,1] should be a finite and also, the first and last points os the partition should be equal to the maximum and minimum of the compact. So how can you take this partition?

Answer (score 1):

Take the uniform partition with length of the subinterval $2/(n\pi)$ then find the variation where your sum will be in the form of harmonic sequence, which is divergent; that's why it is not of bounded variation.