# Does unbounded derivative imply No Lipschitz?

Tags: continuity

We are taught that bounded derivative implies lipschitz. Also, at times, derivative may not exist, yet lipschitz could hold.

I wonder if derivative exists but is unbounded, can we directly say that it is not lipschitz?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If derivative is unbounded at $x$, then you can find two points near the point $x$ which will not follow the Lipschitz continuity definition for any bound $M$.

Comment: Does unbounded at x mean unbounded on some neighborhood of x?

Answer (score 8):

Assume $f$ is Lipschitz and differentiable at $I$ and let
$a\in I$.

$\exists K>0: $

$\forall x\in I - \{a\}$

$|\frac{f(x)-f(a)}{x-a}| \leq K$

then by passage to the limit when $x\to a$, we get

$|f'(a)|\leq K$ and $f'$ is bounded at $ I$.

Comment: Is this answering the question? Lipschitz continuity implies bounded derivative, yes, but this is not the question...

Answer (score -1):

$$f(x) = x \sin\left(\frac1x\right) \text{ on } (0,1)$$ is a Lipschitz function with unbounded derivative

Comment: Do you have a proof?

Comment: This function is not Lipschitz, it is not even bounded variation, see: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/605241/is-fx-x-sin-frac1x-with-f0-0-of-bounded-variation-on-0-1