# Show f(x) is not of bounded variation

Tags: real-analysis, functions

My problem is the following (exercise 4.14 from L Barreira, C Valls, Dynamical systems, an introduction):

Given $f$: $S^1 \rightarrow \mathcal{R}$  defined as:

$x\sin(\frac{\pi}{x})$ for $x\neq0$ and

$f(x) = 0$ for $x=0$

I am supposed to show that for any n$\in \mathbb{N}$:

$\sum_{i=1}^{n-1} |f(x_i) - f(x_{i-1}) | \quad = \quad 4\sum_{i=1}^n\frac{1}{2i +1}$

for the partition of $[0, 1]$ given by $x_0 = 0, \quad x_1 = \frac{2}{2n+1}, \quad x_2 = \frac{1}{2n-1}, \quad ... ,x_{n-1} = \frac{2}{5}, \quad x_n = \frac{2}{3}, \quad x_{n+1} = 1 $

I know that the sum on the right hand side of the above equation in not convergent as n tends to infinity, hence I can conclude that the above equality shows, by definition of bounded variation, that $f(x)$ is indeed not of bdd variation.

My approach was to use induction to show that, for any n the above equation hold, such that all I need to find is a base case, then show the induction step, and I'm done.

By inspection, the natural choice of basecase is $n=2$, however when doing the calculations we get:

$|f(x_1) - f(x_0)| = |\frac{2}{3}\sin(\frac{3\pi}{2}) - 0| = \frac{2}{3} \neq 4\frac{8}{15} = 4(\frac{1}{3} + \frac{1}{5})$

So the equation above does not hold for $n=2$. My question is then, is there an another approach to showing that $f(x)$ is not of bdd variation?

Comment: I do not understand the partition $x_i,i=1...n-1$ you describe here. Why is $x_{n+1}$ defined if it does not appear in the sum?

Comment: [Related](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/605241/is-x-sin1-x-of-bounded-variation?rq=1)

Comment: I don't know either. This is the way the problem is given in the book.