# On the $p$-variation norm: is $||\cdot||_{p-var}\le||\cdot||_{\infty}$?

Tags: real-analysis, p-variation

Let $\Bbb D(\Bbb R_{\ge0},\Bbb R^d)$ be the space of the [Càdlàg functions](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/C%C3%A0dl%C3%A0g).

If $p\ge1$ and $x\in\Bbb D(\Bbb R_{\ge0},\Bbb R^d)$, we define the norm
$$
\overline V_p(x)_T:=|x_0|+\left(\sup_{\pi}\sum_{j=1}^n|x_{t_j}-x_{t_{j-1}}|^p\right)^{1/p}
$$

where $\pi$ varies through all the partions of the interval $[0,T]$ and $|\cdot|$ is the usual euclidean norm.

My problem is the following: is
$$
\overline V_p(x)_T\le\sup_{s\in[0,T]}|x_s|\;\;\;?
$$

I know that for example a.s. the Brownian motion has unbounded total variation but a.s. it is continous; so fixing a suitable $\omega\in\Omega$ we would have a deterministic function which seems to be a counterexample when $p=1$.

But: what can we say for $p\ge1$?

I can't neither prove nor disprove this statement.

Answer (score 2):

The function $f(x)=x\sin\frac1x$ with $f(0)=0$ is the typical example of a bounded continuous function for which the variation is infinite. See this link [bounded not BV](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/605241/is-fx-x-sin-frac1x-with-f0-0-of-bounded-variation-on-0-1)
By modifying this function, with say $f(x)=x^{1/p}\sin\frac1x$, I think you get a counterexample for $p\ge 1$.