# Is $f(x)=x\sin(1/x)$ with $f(0)=0$ of bounded variation on $[0,1]$? - Problem with abs. continuous

Tags: bounded-variation, absolute-continuity

I am having the following trouble:

1. From [Is $f(x)=x\sin(\frac{1}{x})$ with $f(0)=0$ of bounded variation on $[0,1]$?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/605241/is-fx-x-sin-frac1x-with-f0-0-of-bounded-variation-on-0-1), $x\sin(1/x)$ has not bounded variation in $[0,1]$.
2. $x\sin(1/x)$ has derivative $-\cos(1/x)/x + \sin(1/x)$ a.e. and $\int_0^1 (-\cos(1/x)/x + \sin(1/x)) dx=\sin(1)$, i.e., $x\sin(1/x)$ is abs. continuous.
3. Every abs. continuous function is of bounded variation.

What is the error?

Thank you, really much.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

$$g(x) = -\frac{1}{x}\cos\left(\frac{1}{x}\right) + \sin\left(\frac{1}{x}\right)$$ is not integrable on $[0,1]$. Hence the equality

$$\int_0^1 (-\cos(1/x)/x + \sin(1/x)) dx=\sin(1)$$ is wrong and $g$ is not absolutely continuous.

Comment: Not Lebesgue integrable, that is.

Comment: Thank you really much! Please, how can I prove that this function is not Lebesgue integrable on $[0,1]$?

Comment: The result I've posted is from Wolfram... What can be the error?

Comment: Wolfram can make errors... It can make computations without checking if those computations make sense. You have to check that $\int_0^1 \vert g \vert = \infty$.

Comment: Thank you so much, and I've forgotten to put the absolute value